# How to use .hpi files for vim

Tags: cppcheck

I have downloaded a .hpi file for cppcheck as plugin but i don't know how to use. Can anybody help me in this regard.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

HPI files are [Hudson Plug-In](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Plugins) files. They are not [Vim Plug-In](http://www.vim.org/scripts/index.php) files. You cannot use this .hpi file with Vim.

Comment: Then how can i use that plug-in for vim?

Comment: I don't think I could have been any more clear with my answer. Perhaps with bold type for "**cannot**"?

Comment: If you uninstall Vim and install Hudson, this will give you a version of Vim that runs Hudson plugins.